# SpecFlow error on build server

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, specflow

I am getting a strange error on the build server, this does NOT happen locally.

> Error during file generation. The target file 'C:...\AcceptanceTest\Features\HelloWorld.feature.cs'
>   is read-only, but different from the transformation result. This
>   problem can be a sign of an inconsistent source code package. Compile
>   and check-in the current version of the file from the development
>   environment or remove the read-only flag from the generation result.
>   To compile a solution that contains messaging project on a build
>   server, you can also exclude the messaging project from the
>   build-server solution or set the  msbuild
>   project parameter to 'true' in the messaging project file.

I'm not sure what to do to fix this, I don't have a "messaging" project (or know what is being referred too). And the code is the latest

This is the full message (some folder names have been obfuscated):

> 13>C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\packages\SpecRun.Excel.1.1.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow-buildfix.targets(47,5):
>   error : Error during file generation. The target file
>   'C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\PService\Test\PService.AcceptanceTest\Features\HelloWorld.feature.cs'
>   is read-only, but different from the transformation result. This
>   problem can be a sign of an inconsistent source code package. Compile
>   and check-in the current version of the file from the development
>   environment or remove the read-only flag from the generation result.
>   To compile a solution that contains messaging project on a build
>   server, you can also exclude the messaging project from the
>   build-server solution or set the  msbuild
>   project parameter to 'true' in the messaging project file.
>   [C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\PService\Test\PService.AcceptanceTest\PService.AcceptanceTest.csproj]
>       13>C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\packages\SpecRun.Excel.1.1.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow-buildfix.targets(47,5):
>   error : Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\tfsbuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpPWithData.feature.xlsx.cs'.
>   [C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\PService\Test\PService.AcceptanceTest\PService.AcceptanceTest.csproj]
>       13>C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\PService\Test\PService.AcceptanceTest\Features\PWithData.feature.xlsx
>   : error : Generation error: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\tfsbuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpPWithData.feature.xlsx.cs'.
>   [C:\Builds\2\Services\PService\src\PService\Test\PService.AcceptanceTest\PService.AcceptanceTest.csproj]

Answer (score 1):

Delete `HelloWorld.feature.cs` from source control.

TFS will checkout files as read-only during a build and so SpecFlow fails to re-generate the file because it already exists and SpecFlow doesn't overwrite read-only files.

I created a new request for SpecFlow to not automatically add the file to source control here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/592

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the *messaging project* refers to, that's something I haven't seen before.

However the error reads as if the problem is due to an issue with the generation of the `*.feature.cs` from the `*.feature` file, but I am confused as to why this should be happening on the build server. Normally the generation of `*.feature.cs` occurs in the IDE when you save the `*.feature` file. This gets checked in and with some version control systems (VCS) you may end up with a read-only file status.

Your error reads as the build server is trying to re-generate the `*.feature.cs` file and cannot overwrite it.

Some things to check;

- What VCS are you running? Does it leave checked-in files as read-only?
- How are you building the files on the build server? Is there a custom step involved, or is it just a simple compile?
- Can you replicate this error on your machine by setting the `*.feature.cs` to read-only and running the same build script on your local machine?

Good luck.